# Getting rid of HPDeviceMonitoring

Tags: printing

I recently bought a HP MFP M277dw printer (which is by the way really good) and as macOS hadn't driver for it I had to install the HP's software.

This thing is really annoying and what's more concerning, it taking up to 100% cpu time (of one core) while doing absolutely nothing (one would hope).

So I deleted the directory /Library/Printers/hp/Frameworks and killed it.

The problem is that every time I boot this directory with all these crappy apps from HP is being restored.

Is there a way to prevent it?

Regards,
Radek

EDIT (Sun, Feb 4, 2018 16:30:46): I actually just found out that I do not even need to reboot. It install itself within an hour or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall all HP software from your computer. Usually the installer also provides an uninstaller. Prevent from automatic starting by removing those apps from Login Items under Users in System Preferences.

The HP print drivers from Apple directly are really good. And normally the official HP software is not needed to print, copy, scan etc..

There is a big memory leak in the software written by HP.. it has been for several years now. I have seen this issue many times.

Comment: I've never actually noticed HPDeviceMonitoring run at all on my machine & certainly not enough to show at the top end of Activity Monitor, which I have open all the time - I have similar software by HP installed on 2 Macs for an M477fdw with no issues at all.

Comment: No. Unfortunately there is no uninstaller. And it is also not under login items. I have no idea how it's being restored